# Js file not founding a Jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a "clock.js" file:

```js
var FlipClock = function () {
   function increment(num){}
}
var flipClock = FlipClock();
```

and a "run.js" file:

```js
flipClock.increment(1);
```

The index.html file has, in order to load those two files:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/clock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/run.js"></script>
```

When I run index.html, I get this error:

```js
ReferenceError: flipClock is not defined run.js:x:x
```

Anybody can help? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: It seems like your scripts is not loaded, because in your case you have to get another error :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is loaded, since I see the rest of the code of "run.js": it shows me a loaded clock, but that doesn't increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var` keyword, methinks, will localize the variable to a scope. What you need to do is one of the following:

1. Declare `flipClock` as a global variable
2. Export `flipClock`; but I think `export` is only for libraries.

This should make `flipClock` available across files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem! I declared flipClock = FlipClock(); and it works! Thanks again :-)

Comment: But the file has no scope.

Comment: So what should I do? Thanks in advance, Qwertiy.

Answer (score -2):

```
function FlipClock() {
}

FlipClock.prototype.increment = function (num) { }

var flipClock = new FlipClock();
flipClock.increment(1);
```

Comment: tried, nobody changed. I get the same error. Could it be a problem that I call "flipClock.increment(1);" from another function?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11490742)